# Is it possible to connect Mini PCIe Wireless Adapter to Laptop by ExressCard?

Tags: wifi, pci

I want to connect a wireless adapter with mini pcie interface to my laptop that runs `Ubuntu 16.04` through laptop's ExpressCard interface. I want to know if that is possible. Is the wireless adapter going to use the same driver as it would use if connected internally to the laptop?

I have found a converter which converts mini pcie slot to ExpressCard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ExpressCard interface should allow a direct connection to one of the laptop's PCIe lanes, so yes, the same driver should work unless the converter is designed in a strange and overly complex way.